# Are there any collections, which throws exception, if added item is not unique?

Tags: java, exception, collections

Are there any collections, which throws exception, if added item is not unique?

With input exception message or special exception.

Comment: That would be unusual. The normal way is to have something like `addIfAbsent` and you can check the return value of that.

Comment: I'd be surprised, even a `Set` doesn't, it just returns `false` if it was already present.

Comment: But you could creates your collection, simply by using a `Set`, in your add method, if the original `add()` return false, throw the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any collection that would do it.

A simply homemade version would be to create a subclass of `java.util.HashSet<E>`

In that class, you provide every constructor and override the [`Set.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add) 
to throw an exception if the `super.add(e)` return false. (see [Mehdi Javan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093852/4391450)  answer for a first implementation)

If you want to be able to use any `Set`, just use a method to do it for you that accept a `Set`.

```
public void addIfAbsent(Set<E> set, E e) throws TheException {
     if(!set.add(e)) {//throw exception }
}
```

Since we are here, you can make it work for any [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) ...

```
public void addIfAbsent(Collection<E> set, E e) throws TheException {
     if(c.contains(e)) { //throw exception }
     c.add(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't such collection in `Java`. However, third-party libraries may contain such collection. In Java, `Set` implementations like `HashSet` and `TreeSet` prevent adding duplicate objects. But, they don't throw exceptions if you try to add a duplicated object. Their `add` method simply return `false` if the object already exists in the collection. If it's not what you want you can extend one of those classes and override add method and throw an exception. Something like this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MySet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if(!super.add(e))
            throw new RuntimeException("The object already exists in the collection.");

        return true;
    }
}
```